# How to recover all the data which I lost- Ubuntu 20.0.4

Tags: apt, 20.04, wine

After running `sudo apt install wine` command I lost all of my data.

Please let me know how I can recover all the data.

Comment: I  can see all the data through terminal but in particular folder.

Comment: Packages aren't stored in directories which contain data; so your *theory* or *explanation* on why the data got corrupted imply your system is very sick and you should be restoring data... instead trying to assess if your system is healthy or should be just retired/replaced.  Your describing what is more likely faulty hardware (failing drive), or operator error - not the result of a package addition (unless prior problems were ignored and the command you offer is what made you finally aware of the already existing problem...)   Your issue doesn't make sense.

Comment: No, But able to see file and folder using terminal but, I did not see folder for finder and like others. but when i go using terminal all folders i can see same as before.

Comment: Can you maybe show us the exact commands you put into the terminal when installing wine? Did you only enter that one line? If there are other lines such as moving of directories, please mention so we can help

Comment: No, I just use same command which i mentioned, While it was running i see that its saying removing, removing this package so aborted it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover deleted files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files)

Comment: No, It did not worked. I ran "sudo apt-get install wine64". Later that i did not had any option so rebooted system again.